# Finding words in csv Text

Tags: python, csv

I've a problem with my Python code. I want to find out the occurence of a words in csv , but somehow the occurences don't scale up:

```
occurences = 0
with open ("text.csv", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        splitted = line.strip().split(' ')
        print(splitted)

    if splitted == 'bike':
        continue 
        occurences = occurences + int(splitted)

print(occurences)
```

The output is 0 even if bike occurences 3 times in text.
Thanks in advance, I'm Python beginner and the solution might be very simple to you :-)

Finn

Comment: `occurences = occurences + int(splitted)` whaat

Comment: Why do you have a `continue` in there?

Comment: This will not work ```if splitted == 'bike':``` because ```splitted``` is a list. Use this ```if 'bike' in splitted:``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
x = ['this is a bike yo bike hahahaha bike','no bike here']
occurences = 0
for line in x:
    splitted = line.strip().split(' ')
    print(splitted)

    if 'bike' in splitted:
#           continue 
        occurences = occurences + splitted.count('bike')

print(occurences)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
occurences = 0
with open ("text.csv", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        splitted = line.strip().split(' ')
        print(splitted)

        count = splitted.count('bike')
        occurences = occurences + count

print(occurences)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str.count()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm):

test.csv:

```
bike no more car bike
car car car
hello car
okay bike
what is this bike
```

**Hence**:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    occurences = contents.count("bike")    
print(occurences)   # 4
```

**EDIT**:

one-liner:

```
print([sum(line.count("bike") for line in open('test.csv'))][0]) # 4
```

Comment: Your code seemed to work fine, I checked it myself. Was it wrong? Why did you delete it? (Not a downvoter)

Comment: Idk, people were downvoting and I got scared! :3

Comment: Hahaha, don't mind that. Thanks for posting your idea anyway! Stay +ve :)

Comment: When I said *screw this answer* I did not literally mean to screw it. EASY everyone! xD

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this. It is clear, Pythonic, and concise. Take my upvote.

Comment: BTW, the example file is ```test.csv``` and you are opening ```people.csv``` :-), but that doens't take the merit of a good code snippet.

Comment: Thank you fellas! Yes, that was a typo since I edited this post for one to many times! :3

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
occurrences = Counter()
with open ("text.csv", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        occurrences.update(line.strip().split())
print(ocurrences['bike'])
```